# How to get drop-down menu in FLTK?

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, fltk

I am making a GUI with FLTK and I am wondering if there is a widget for something resembling a drop-down menu. I want one value to be shown, then have the user click the value (or something else associated with it), then a list of values be shown for the user to select one from, then the list collapse again. I have been unsuccessful finding documentation for a widget that can do this so I thought I would ask. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [FL_Choice](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Choice.html).

Comment: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/examples/filechooser-test.cxx has a complete example of FL_Choice.